# multiple clauses in nosql database like firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I made a app where I can see the university name for my bachelor available for me depending on my secondary and higher secondary result. So, I made a database(UniInfo) with three attribute (universityName, secondaryResult, higherSecondaryResult). Here user will input their secondary and higherSecondary result and can see the available university list.

If i write my query with sql, then -

```
SELECT universityName
FROM UniInfo
WHERE inputSecondaryResult >= secondaryResult 
  AND inputHigherSecondaryResult >= higherSecondaryResult;
```

But I made this app with Firebase which is nosql database. In nosql we can not retrieve data with multiple clause (AND operation).  Help me out to write this query. Thanks.

Comment: I saw that earlier. Its not helping me as the type of attributes here is string and my result attribute type is double. So, I can't merge the values and put it on different index.

Comment: There is no way to do that type of query in one go on the database, since even with synthetic multi-value properties you can only do one range filter. The linked answer explains your other options, which is: do one of the filters on the client.